# Problems iterating through Foreign Collections with ORMLite

Tags: ormlite

Am having an issue trying to use Ormlite `ForeignCollection` with the following classes. I believe I have my Run & Waypoint classes correctly annotated. (Run has a collection of WayPoints). However when I attempt to access WayPoints (see third code extract) my `CloseableIterator` returns null when I call `hasNext()`. When I test this out with the emulator I first generate a number of WayPoints for the Run and store them. I then try to access those WayPoints through an instance of Run. Just to complete the picture without dumping too much code here, the `ForeignCollection<WayPoint>` object is passed to the Contender constructor by calling

```
run.getWayPoints();
```

Here's how I am creating a WayPoint and storing it :: - When GPSLocation.onLocationChanged() fires and the state is GPS_STATE_RUNNING, then a call to createWayPoint() is made. This instantiates a WayPoint, sets lng/lat values and also sets the handle to the associated Run instance, which at this point has not yet been stored itself to the db. An Intent is sent to another class that calls back in on GPSLocation.updateWayPointWithElapsedTime() where the WayPoint is finally stored to the db. When a run completes an external class calls storeRun() which stores the Run instance. I am beginning to wonder if storing a WayPoint when it's associated Run instance is itself not yet stored is part of the problem.

** Note :: the classes will not compile as they are cutdown to show sections relavent to the question.

```
@DatabaseTable
public class Run {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId=true)
    private int id;

    @DatabaseField(foreign=true,foreignAutoRefresh=true)
    private Route route;

    @ForeignCollectionField
    private ForeignCollection<WayPoint> wayPoints; 

    @DatabaseField
    private Date date;

    @DatabaseField
    private long time;

    public ForeignCollection<WayPoint> getWayPoints() {
        return wayPoints;
    }
}

@DatabaseTable
public class WayPoint {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId=true)
    private int id;

    @DatabaseField
    private int latitude;

    @DatabaseField
    private int longitude;

    @DatabaseField
    private int time; // offset 

    @DatabaseField(foreign=true,foreignAutoRefresh=true) 
    private Run run;
}    

public class Contender implements Comparable<Contender> {

    private int accumulatedDistance;
    private int interpolatedDistance;
    private WayPoint startPoint;
    CloseableIterator itr;
    private int id;
    WayPoint previous;
    WayPoint next;

    public Contender(ForeignCollection<WayPoint> wayPoints, WayPoint startPoint, int id) {

        this.startPoint = startPoint;
        this.id = id;
        itr = wayPoints.closeableIterator();

        if(itr.hasNext()) { 
            next = (WayPoint)itr.next();
        }
        else {
            Log.e("@@@", "no way points");
        }

        Log.i("@@@", "wayPoints size is " + wayPoints.size()); 
    }
}


public class GPSLocation extends Service implements LocationListener {
    private Run run;
    private WayPoint  wayPoint;
    private int distanceTravelled;

    @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
            startLocationUpdates = new ArrayList<Location>();

            Log.i(LOGTAG, "GPSLocation Service Running...");
        }

        public void startRunning() {

            setState(GPS_STATE_RUNNING);
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            run = new Run();
            run.setRoute(route);
            run.setDate(new Date());
        }

        public void storeRun(long elapsedTime) {

            // if first run and end point not set then set end point
            run.setTime(elapsedTime);
            route.addToCumulativeDistance(distanceTravelled);
            DatabaseManager.getInstance().storeRun(run);
            DatabaseManager.getInstance().updateRoute(route);

            resetGlobalState();
        }

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            previousLocation = currentLocation;
            currentLocation = location;

            Intent i = null; 
            boolean startActivity = true;

            switch(state)
            {
                case GPS_STATE_SETTING_START_LOCATION:
                    startLocationUpdates.add(location);

                    if(startLocationAccepted())
                    {
                        i = new Intent(this, AddRoute.class);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        i.setAction("acquired");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        startActivity = false; // waiting for more location data
                    }
                    break;

                case GPS_STATE_READY:
                    if(!atLocation(ROUTE_START, location, ROUTE_DELIMITER_REQUIRED_PROXIMITY))
                    {
                        setState(GPS_STATE_AWAITING_ARRIVAL_AT_START_LOCATION);
                        i = new Intent(this, Running.class);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        i.setAction("proximity_update");
                    }
                    break;

                case GPS_STATE_AWAITING_ARRIVAL_AT_START_LOCATION:
                    i = new Intent(this, Running.class);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    if(atLocation(ROUTE_START, location, ROUTE_DELIMITER_REQUIRED_PROXIMITY))
                    {
                        setState(GPS_STATE_READY);
                        i.setAction("ready");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i.setAction("proximity_update");
                    }
                    break;

                case GPS_STATE_RUNNING:
                    createWayPoint(location);
                    i = new Intent(this, Running.class);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    if(atLocation(ROUTE_END, location, ROUTE_DELIMITER_REQUIRED_PROXIMITY) 
                            && (distanceTravelled > ROUTE_DELIMITER_REQUIRED_PROXIMITY))
                    {
                        i.setAction("at_end");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i.setAction("update");
                    }

                    distanceTravelled += currentLocation.distanceTo(previousLocation);  
                    i.putExtra("distanceTravelled", distanceTravelled);
                    setState(GPS_STATE_RUNNING_UPDATE);
                    break;

                default:
                    // error
            }
        }

        private void createWayPoint(Location location) {

            wayPoint = new WayPoint();
            wayPoint.setLatitude(LocationMath.degreesToMicroDegrees(location.getLatitude()));
            wayPoint.setLongitude(LocationMath.degreesToMicroDegrees(location.getLongitude()));
            wayPoint.setRun(run);
        }

        /*
         * Now we have the elapsed time from the Running Activity, we can store this WayPoint
         */
        public void updateWayPointWithElapsedTime(long elapsedTime) {

            // TODO::check the time value is correct
            wayPoint.setTimeOffset((int)elapsedTime);
            DatabaseManager.getInstance().storeWayPoint(wayPoint);
            setState(GPS_STATE_RUNNING); 
        }
    }
```

Excerpts from DatabaseManager -->

```
public void storeWayPoint(WayPoint point) {
        try {
            getHelper().getWayPointDao().create(point);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public void storeRun(Run run) {
    try {
        getHelper().getRunDao().create(run);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problems with the code you've posted Chris.  Therefore I suspect that you are not inserting the `WayPoint`s like you think you are.  Have you verified that they are in the database?  Have you tried a query using the `WayPoint` DAO directly?

```
// what does this return?
List<WayPoint> wayPoints = wayPointDao.queryForAll();
```

> I first generate a number of WayPoints for the Run and store them

Also, make sure you have inserted the `Run` field into the `Run` table and set it on each `WayPoint` *before* you do the create for the `WayPoint`. You should be doing something like:

```
Run run1 = new Run(...);
runDao.create(run1);
...
WayPoint wayPoint1 = new WayPoint(...);
wayPoint1.setRun(run1);
wayPointDao.create(wayPoint1);
...
```

Another way you can insert is to use the foreign collection itself:

```
// create a foreign collection we can add to
run.wayPoints = runDao.getEmptyForeignCollection("wayPoints");
// now if you add something to the collection, it gets created in the DAO as well
run.wayPoints.add(wayPoint1);
```

If you edit your question and show us the code used to insert the `WayPoint`s into the database, I'll edit my answer to provide more information.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Gray. Will try that out shortly. Have posted the rest of the relavent code. I like the idea of adding to the foreign collection itself. Is there a performance difference in doing that compared with adding individual WayPoints?

Comment: ok so fetching WayPoints back out of the db shows that there are values for every field apart from the run field. When I store a WayPoint I have a valid instance of Run and I set it into the WayPoint, but that instance of Run has not yet itself been stored to the db. I am going to try storing the Run instance before storing any WayPoints and see if that makes a difference. Thanks again for your feedback Gray. Will update later.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem @Chris.  Sorry I should have mentioned that as well.

Comment: That's great. Help is much appreciated.